# How to reduce repeatedly and dynamically generated html

Tags: html

I am in the middle of revising a website and it has a significant problem with rendering time. I looked into what is causing the problem and it turns out that table-generating mechanism that I am using takes way too much time.

As needed data gets queried from DB, the table is dynamically generated in repeated format. (as shown below in the code) Table size increases as scrolling down to bottom. Instead of generating additional table every time additional queries are done, is there any way to get by and reduce the rendering time?

Here is a snippet of HTML structure generated. (there are more than 10000 rows in the same format but with different contents)

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

```
            <tr class="doc_field_vendor_item">
                <td width="150px" align="center" class="item">
                    <div id="invno1127">16011304</div>
                </td>
                <td width="200px" align="center" class="item">
                    <div id="invDate1127">2016-01-13</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="totalDue1127">$&nbsp;416.00&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day301127">&nbsp;$ 416.00&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day31_451127">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day46_601127">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day60_Over1127">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="doc_field_vendor_item_bg">
                <td width="150px" align="center" class="item">
                    <div id="invno1128">16011305</div>
                </td>
                <td width="200px" align="center" class="item">
                    <div id="invDate1128">2016-01-13</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="totalDue1128">$&nbsp;129.60&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day301128">&nbsp;$ 129.60&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day31_451128">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day46_601128">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
                <td width="130px" align="right" class="item">
                    <div id="day60_Over1128">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I assume you're getting all the rows from the DB or getting a small subset of them, many times, then passing each row into some function that generates the table row correct? If so, seeing the code that does that would help us be able to look for anything that might be affecting performance. Otherwise you could try and move the table generation to JS using ajax to make it seem like it's going fast. You could also do a combo of like 1000 rows in php then the rest in JS, though that can be hard to follow later.

Comment: How is data queried, on page load or by ajax ?

Comment: Move the width and alignment elements into the item class in the styling. If the `div` inside the `td` is not being used for something remove it and just leave the data. Could also move the `id` to the `td` and get rid of the `divs`.

Comment: there's no php here (it's misleading) or database code. That makes your question unclear and possibly too broad. Can you update your question so that there is relevant code that we can work with? Otherwise, I'll vote to close as unclear. You could ping `@username` us if you need (more) help.

Comment: Look into Caching pages

Comment: there's also no javascript, making both php/javascript tags misleading to members who follow those tags.

Comment: @samuraiseoul im getting all the rows from the DB and display using while loop. Just wondering, how would ajax increase the performance where each request using ajax will require RTT from client to server? Wouldn't it be faster to load all the data and process it without having to request more data every time?

Comment: @SimranjitSingh page load

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for the advice. I thought I had php and javascript code attached as well since it is being used in the system. I have just removed unnecessary tags.

Comment: @ChadK data changes quite often. I can cache the format but the contents in it :(

Comment: @R.Roh You're welcome and thank "you" :-) As already said, you can look into using ajax and with jQuery's `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/ which would "load" a page. I've done this before and it works quite well. There are many ways to do this though, it just depends if you want to load more as someone scrolls down a bit and loads it automatically or with a button. I'm not your guy for the JS/jQuery stuff though. TBH, when I need functionality as such, I just Google it and most of the times, I'm led back here on Stack.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for help. I will surely do so :)

Comment: @R.Roh IT would not increase performance but it would make the page load faster for the user, and if you ran multiple ajax queries to load the data bit by bit, then it would have a lower load on each request and a faster initial load for the user. Without seeing some code I can't really help you too much here. Depending on how you build the html I do believe there are performance gains to be had as well. But that's outside the scope of a comment on the question.

Comment: @samuraiseoul Sorry for the fact that I am only allowed to share the limited scope of the code. I thought I can only have a single AJAX query for a single DB each time. (linear processing instead of parallel processing) I will try having multiple AJAX queries. Anyways, I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @R.Roh, so how are you putting things on the page? Are you building the ENTIRE table and outputting it? Are you looping through each row and echoing out the tr, then the td for each of the relevant rows? I'm pretty sure echoing out as its looped will be much faster than appending it and building a huge string though I'm not 100% sure. Even building each row then echoing out that will be faster. Also is the html in a string or are you writing it using like `<?php foreach($row as $field => $value): ?> Then putting straight html and occasionally echoing the var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10000 rows is a lot. You probably don't need to display 10000 rows all at once.

One solution is to paginate the data. Only display 300 rows per page. This is probably easier to do.

Another solution is to render only a fraction of the data initially, and make ajax requests to server side on demand as user scroll down the table. Websites like Facebook and Twitter has this kind of thing. Recall that you can scroll down on these sites infinitely and always load more posts. However, making requests also takes time, which you can optimize by caching some rows ahead of time. For Example, each time you send 1000 rows to the client side, and only render 600 rows on the page, and only make 300 rows visible to the user. When user scrolls down, you render more from cache and make requests to ask for more data from server.

Comment: Good idea! I've only considered caching in a longer term. I will definitely give this a try. Thank you :)